# NDSolve Issue with initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations, pattern-matching

I am trying to implement a Poincare section for a gravitational movement on the plane $(x,y)$.

Here is the code I wrote

```
PoincareSection[cix_, civx_, ciy_, civy_]:=
    q = 0.9;
    Rc = 0.14;
    v0 = 1;
    Φ[x_, y_] := 1/2 v0^2 Log[Rc^2 + x^2 + (y/q)^2];
    h1 = x'[t] == vx[t];
    h2 = vx'[t] == -D[Φ[x, y], x] /. x -> x[t] /. y -> y[t];
    h3 = y'[t] == vy[t];
    h4 = vy'[t] == - D[Φ[x, y], y] /. x -> x[t] /. y -> y[t];
    Return[Reap[NDSolve[{h1, h2, h3, h4,
    x[0] == cix, vx[0] == civx, y[0] == ciy, vy[0] == civy,
    WhenEvent[{y[t] == 0, vy[t] > 0}, Sow[{x[t], vx[t]}]]},
    {x[t], vx[t], y[t], vy[t]},
    {t, 0, 100}]][[2]]];
```

However, when I try to run this code, I always get the following error:

> NDSolve::ndinnt: Initial condition civx is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers.

I have tried using `N` and pattern `_?NumericQ` for the parameters of the function, but that didn't work out...

Any ideas what may be causing the problem ?
(If you see any other improvements I could make to my code I would be happy to hear them...)

Comment: `when I try to run this code` Can you give an example of how you called this code?

Comment: may be something like this? `PoincareSection[cix_, civx_, ciy_, civy_] := Module[{q = 0.9,
    Rc = 0.14,
    v0 = 1},
   \[CapitalPhi][x_, y_] := 1/2 v0^2 Log[Rc^2 + x^2 + (y/q)^2];
   h1 = x'[t] == vx[t];
   h2 = vx'[t] == -D[\[CapitalPhi][x, y], x] /. x -> x[t] /. y -> y[t];
   h3 = y'[t] == vy[t];
   h4 = vy'[t] == -D[\[CapitalPhi][x, y], y] /. x -> x[t] /. y -> y[t];
   Reap[NDSolve[{h1, h2, h3, h4, x[0] == cix, vx[0] == civx, 
      y[0] == ciy, vy[0] == civy, 
      WhenEvent[{y[t] == 0, vy[t] > 0}, Sow[{x[t], vx[t]}]]}, {x[t], 
      vx[t], y[t], vy[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]]];`

Comment: @Nasser : To call the code, I would simply copy it in a notenook and press Shift+Enter

Comment: @chris : Using Module to declare local variable solved my issue, without even using _?NumericQ

Comment: Clearly I did not mean how to define the function, I meant to call it. You only show the definition of the function, not the call itself. One defines a function, and then calls it. I asked for an example of the call itself.

Comment: Well, I should say it's more appropriate to mark this question as a duplicate if this question is in this site: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8316921/1551513 . But I think it's also acceptable to treat it as a simple mistake?